# Responsive Design: Scrolling JS/JQuery Rotating Banner Using Percentages (not px)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-rotation

I'm almost there. However, there is a bug which I can't work out. I think the problem is to do with using percentages rather than pixels (as I want the banner to resize for different screen widths).

The banner scrolls every 5 seconds, but only gets to the 3rd image before heading back to the beginning. Also - when I resize the window very small, the banner only rotates between the first two images (and sometimes scrolls to a non-existent 5th image, displaying white space).

I've played about with the Javascript. Changing the IF statement to be < -400% (still rotates across 3 images). When I set it to < -800% it goes to 2 images, and < -1000% it never returns to the beginning! I'm very confused, but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="subwrapper3">

        <div class="bannerwrapmain">
            <img src="/images/banner-image-1.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="bannerwrapmain">
            <img src="/images/banner-image-2.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="bannerwrapmain">
            <img src="/images/banner-image-3.jpg" />
        </div>      

        <div class="bannerwrapmain">
            <img src="/images/banner-image-4.jpg" />
        </div>  

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper 
{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
}

#subwrapper3
{
    width:400%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.bannerwrapmain
{
    display: block;   
    width:25%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    float:left;
}

.bannerwrapmain img
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    height:auto;
    border:none;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
window.setInterval(function(){

if ($("#subwrapper3").css("marginLeft") < "-300%") { 
    $("#subwrapper3").animate({ marginLeft: '0%' });
} else {
    $("#subwrapper3").animate({ marginLeft: '-=100%' });        
}

}, 5000);
```

Comment: have you checked what `.css("marginLeft")` is giving back? you campare with a string here. same as comparing "a" > "b" ?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your main wrapper to a fixed dimension, say 1000px. then your subwrapper to 100%, and your images to max-width:100%;

```
#wrapper{width:1000px;}
#subwrapper3, .bannerwrapmain{width:100%;}
.bannerwrapmain img{max-width:100%;}
```

You can then use media queries to change the main wrapper width based on screen size, and the contained elements will scale with it:

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px){    
    #wrapper{width:500px;}
}
```

I created a content slider a few months ago, it may be of some help to you... http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/mHyBv